A basic question/confusion about Artin-Schreier covers
Let us assume that $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and assume that it is algebraically closed. From field theory, we know that  a cyclic degree $p$ extension of $F=k(x)$ is an Artin-Schreier extension $k(x)[y]/(y^p-y-f)$ where $f\in k(x)$.
On the geometric side, we have a $p$-cover $C\to \mathbb{P}^1$ where $C$ is the Artin-Schreier curve with affine model $y^p-y=f$ and the cover is given by $[x:y:z]\mapsto [x:z]$.
My confusion: This doesn't look like it should be surjective.
If we write $f$ in its partial fraction decomposition, $f(x)=f_{\infty}(x)+\sum_{i} f_{b_i}(\frac{1}{x-b_i})$ (here $f_\infty$ and $f_{b_i}$ are polynomials), what point maps to $[b_i:1]\in \mathbb{P}^1$?
Edit: Let me be a bit clearer. $y^p-yz^{p-1}=z^pf(x/z)$ be a projective model.
For example, consider $y^p-y=1/(x-b_1)$ with projective model $(y^p-yz^{p-1})(x-b_1z)=z^{p+1}$. If $x=b_1t, z=b_1t$ this gives us that $0=t^{p+1}$. So there is no point of the on the curve with projective coordinates $[b_1: * :1]$. So this looks like there won't be a point on $C$ that maps to $[b_1: 1]\in \mathbb{P}^1$
If $z=0$, this gives us $y^px=0$ so the points at infinity are $[0:1:0]$ and $[1:0:0]$.

If you only look at an affine part of $C$, there doesn't seem to be any reason to expect it to surject onto $\mathbb P^1$. Or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

@LazzaroCampeotti I added more details to what I meant.

The map is induced by the linear projection $\mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ from the point $(0:1:0)$, and it is easy to see that the image of $(0:1:0)$ is exactly $(b_1:1)$.

@Sasha Can you clarify what you mean? If $(0:1:0)$ maps to $(b_1:1)$ then what maps to $(b_2:1)$?

I don't understand your question (there is no $b_2$ in the equation of your curve). If you project a plane curve from a smooth point of that curve then the image of that point corresponds to the tangent line at that point to the curve. The tangent line at $(0:1:0)$ to your curve is $x - b_1z = 0$, so the image is the point $(b_1:1)$.

@Sasha I thought you were referring to the general case where $f$ had poles at other places as well. I see now what you meant by a linear projection.

In a more general case there won't be a smooth plane model for your curve, but still the situation will be the same --- some points "at infinity" will map to the points $(b_i:1)$.

Although I don't think I can make any explicit computations without knowing $f$ (I'd be gladly proven wrong), I can hopefully explain where to look in order to see that this map is, indeed, surjective. This is a long answer, I apologize, but hopefully it will make things clearer for you as it did for me, when I recently struggled on similar issues.
First of all, any nonconstant rational map between two nonsingular curves extends to a well defined surjective morphism. So there's no doubt that $C \rightarrow \Bbb P^1$ is surjective. The question now is: why does it seem like we cannot find the pre-images of $[b:1]$, where $b$ is any pole of $f$ ?
Let us begin by a (much) simpler case: the cover of $\Bbb P^1$ given by the equation $y^2 - \prod_{i=1}^{2d} (x_i - a_i)$ (where each root is simple), which we denote $X \rightarrow \Bbb P^1$. This corresponds to the field extension $L:=k(x)[y]/(y^2 - \prod_i (x_i - a_i))$ over $k(x)$. We now use the following important property of morphisms between complete nonsingular curves:

If $U = \operatorname{Spec}(A) \subseteq \Bbb P^1$ is an open affine, $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is an open affine isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$, where $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$.

So let's try to find an open cover of $X$, namely the pre-image of the cover of $\Bbb P^1$ by $\Bbb A^1$ and $\Bbb P^1 \setminus \{0\}$.

$V=f^{-1}(\Bbb A^1)$: the integral closure of $k[x]$ in $L$ is $k[x,y]/(y^2 - \prod_i (x_i - a_i))$. Indeed, the quotient shows that $y$ is integral over $k[x]$, and the ring obtained is integrally closed (Hartshorne Exercice II.6.4).
$W=f^{-1}(\Bbb P^1 \setminus \{0\})$: the integral closure of $k[x^{-1}]=k[z]$ in $L$ is $k[z,t]/(t^2 - \prod_i (1 - a_iz))$, where $z:=x^{-1}$ and $t = yx^{-d}$. I will let you verify that this makes sense.

Any point on $V$ can be specified by its coordinates $(x,y)$ (satisfying the equation), and similarly on $W$ with $(z,t)$ (and the other equation). The map $V \rightarrow \Bbb A^1$ is quite clearly given by $(x,y) \mapsto x$, and similarly for $W \rightarrow \Bbb P^1 \setminus \{0\}$, $(z,t) \mapsto z = x^{-1}$ (and recall that $z=0$ denotes the point at infinity of $\Bbb P^1$). We see this from the corresponding map on rings, which is the inclusion.
Now let me link this example with your troubles. Because I originally started with the equation $y^2 - \prod_{i=1}^{2d} (x_i - a_i)$, which is tailored to look nice over $\Bbb A^1$, this form makes it difficult to understand the pre-image of $\infty$ for $X \rightarrow \Bbb P^1$. For instance, how many points are there in this fiber ? But, if we consider the neighborhood $W$ defined above, it is quite clear that there are two pre-images of $\infty$, which are given by the coordinates $(z,t)=(0,\pm 1)$.
The takeaway from this is that the easy way to "see for sure" the pre-image of a point in a morphism of curves is to explicit the affine neighborhoods in convenient sets of coordinates. And now, for the grand finale...
There is nothing special about $\infty$ in the example above. The reason why we need to look at a different neighborhood is the following: we can express $\prod_i (x_i - a_i)$ in its "true form" as a rational function on $\Bbb P^1$:
$$\prod_i (x_i - a_i) = \frac{\prod_i (x_i - a_iz)}{z^{2d}}.$$
The right-hand-side is a rational function on $\Bbb P^1$ in the sense that it is a quotient of two homogeneous polynomials of the same degree, in the variables $x$ and $z$. Now we see that $\infty$ is a pole of this function: in order to deal with it, we had to change the equation to an equivalent one, in which it is no longer a pole, and then consider the integral closure of $k[z]$ in the quotient field with respect to that new equation.
Now, this case was doable because all the poles were concentrated in $\infty$. For a more general polynomial, where poles are scattered all over, and multiplicities are going wild, you have to be careful with your initial cover of $\Bbb P^1$, and then find the integral closures of those peculiar open affines (which can be a hard task !).
In conclusion, here is what I believe may have confused you. When you wrote that the map $C \rightarrow \Bbb P^1$ was given by $[x,y,z] \mapsto [x,z]$, I think you may have assumed that there was a convenient covering of $\Bbb P^1$ for which the maps have a similar look as in the cases of $V \rightarrow \Bbb A^1$ (and similar for $W$) above. But if your function $f$ has poles over $\Bbb A^1$ (i.e. the $b_i$'s), the integral closure of $k[x]$ in the field $k(x)[y]/(y^p - y - f)$ is certainly not $k[x,y]/(y^p - y - f)$:

for once, the expression $y^p - y - f$ does not lie in the ring $k[x,y]$, so this quotient is not well defined
if you shrink down $\Bbb A^1$ to an open subset $U$ avoiding the poles $b_i$'s (so as to make the $\frac{1}{x-b_i}$ regular functions), then you can indeed find similar looking expression for a quotient ring, BUT even then, there is no guarantee that the ring you want to write is integrally closed: you may have to add additional elements. In that case, the morphism you find in the end will indeed be a projection onto the coordinate $x$, and that coordinate will of course never equal some $b_i$, because we worked over $U$ which avoids every $b_i$.

So how do we deal with the $b_i$'s ? Pick one, let $x' = \frac{1}{x-b_i}$, change the equation to be nicely expressed in terms of $x'$ without poles at $x'=0$ (factor some powers of $x'$), and do the whole "integrally closed" shenanigans all over. Only then will you find an explicit expression for a projection map, but it is not gonna be in terms of the nice initial coordinates $[x:z]$.
In this story, the Artin-Shreier nature of the cover only impacts how easily you can find the integral closures of the rings for the cover of $\Bbb P^1$.

Let me try to see if I understood what you said. In the hyperelliptic case, $$k(x)[y]/(y^2-\prod_{i=1}^{2d}(x-a_i)$$, things were nice because the integral model is what one expects.
Let me use an actual example and say we are working with $k(x)y$. $f: C\to \mathbb{A}^1$ and say it lifts to maps of complete nonsingular curves, $\tilde{f}: \tilde{C}\to \mathbb{P}^1$. $$\tilde{f}(\mathbb{P}^1-\infty)$$ is isomorphic to $\text{Spec} B$ where $k[x]\subset B\subset k(x)[y]/(y^p-y-1/x)$. (continued)

If I shrink to avoid the pole at $0$, we are looking at the integral closure of $k[x]$ in $k(x)[y]/(xy^p-xy-1)$. But $y$ isn't integral over $k[x]$ so $\text{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy^p-xy-1)\to \text{Spec} k[x]$ wouldn't even be a finite map.

I'd say in that case that the right equation is perhaps $(xy)^p - x^{p-1}(xy) - x^{p-1}$ (multiply everything by $x^p$ so as to  find a monic polynomial again after a change of variables). So you can say that $t=xy$ is integral over $k[x]$. Now we should still check that $k[x,t]/(t^p - x^{p-1}t-x^{p-1})$ is integrally closed.

Unfortunately, the ring $k[x,t]/(t^p-x^{p-1}t-x^{p-1})$ might not be integrally closed.
$y^p-y=1/x\implies y^{2p}-2y^{p+1}+y^2=1/x^2\implies x^py^{2p}-2x^py^{p+1}+x^{p}y^2-x^{p-2}=0$. So $t=xy^2$ satisifies $t^{p}-2x^{(p-1)/2}t^{(p+1)/2}+x^{p-1}t-x^{p-2}=0$. Similar algebraic relationship holds for $xy^i$ for $i=1,...,n$ (where $n$ depends on $p$).
